# Are there any good IDE's for C, C# and C++?

Tags: c++, c#, c, ide

I've just finished python and I'm heading towards the game development area.

I'm wanting to learn C#, and I need an IDE for it, albeit I also need a C IDE, for my projects.

Are there any IDE's that support these languages? C/C#/C++

I need to know, because I'm wanting to make a game in Unity.

I found that Visual Studio supports it, but its size is **TOO BIG**

Other than that, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Can you please define "good": what features do you need, what is important to you, what OS should it run on, how much money would you spend if needed, how big is "too big", etc? Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: There's also VS Code (which I believe is smaller but I've only looked at it not really used it myself). Personally I use Visual Studio for C# (and have done for well over a decade) as comment above I'm wondering why you see it as 'too big'?

Comment: 2GB is too big for me, <2GB is okay.

Comment: What platform are you targeting?  That may impact the IDE you can use.

Answer (score 2):

It does sound like you should give VS Code a try, for the following reason:

- It has a small footprint ~200mb (and is less than 100mb to download). See [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements#:~:text=Visual%20Studio%20Code%20is%20a,easily%20run%20on%20today's%20hardware](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements#:%7E:text=Visual%20Studio%20Code%20is%20a,easily%20run%20on%20today%27s%20hardware).
- It supports C# with Unity https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity
- It supports C/C++ (but note it does not include a compiler or debugger so the install of that will be on top of the above footprint https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)
- As your familiar with Python it's worth knowing it also supports that (see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)
- It's free!

Personally I'd prefer to get hardware that can run Visual Studio Community (also free), and it's worth being aware there are limitations to VS Code (see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/FAQ , Microsoft bill it as a 'code editor' rather than full integrated development environment) but it seems to meet your initial requirements at least.

Comment: I'm currently using PyCharm for my python projects, if I use VS, can I delete PyCharm and transfer all my python projects to VS? or is it a bad idea?

Comment: I'm not a Python Dev so can't really compare - I'd say try VS Code first as see if it does all you want :)

Answer (score 0):

VS Code is a great editor. It is not an IDE per se, but supports debugging, auto-completion  and many other features, mainly through it's vast catalog of plugins. It is cross-platform, very lightweight and has excellent support for C, C# and C++.

Comment: Could you please add a link on where to obtain the software, and mention its pricing? Thanks!

Comment: I'd say that whether you consider VS Code and IDE or not is very much dependent on your definition. While MS seem keen to differentiate between VS Code editor and Visual Studio IDE I think that's more to do with product separation rather than VS Code being definitively not an IDE.

Comment: @Izzy You can easily Google Visual Studio Code and it is free. https://code.visualstudio.com/?wt.mc_id=DX_841432

Comment: @EricS thanks. But answers here should not require "googling" details (apart from me not "googling" but rather "searxing" ;)

Comment: @Izzy You are, of course, right.